# When having String and int as an output - how do I print string first?

Tags: java, string, input, integer, output

This code doesn't work, whenever I as an user input String data first and then int data, it just accepts input and doesn't print out the data. If I change:

```
String name = input.nextLine();
int age = input.nextInt();
```

position of these two code blocks, and enter int first and String as second value after then it happily prints first int number and then String. Please help out how to solve it. I want to be able Name and Family name first and then I want to have age.

```
package package1;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class experiment {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        try {
            System.out.println("Please enter your age and name: ");

            String name = input.nextLine();
            int age = input.nextInt();

            System.out.println("Your age is: " + age);
            System.out.println("Your name is: " + name);
        } finally {
            input.close();
        }
    }

}
```

My input is:

> Aks Eyeless 2022

Comment: How are you inputting? Do you enter `name` and `age` each in a different line, or the same one (like separated by a space)?

Comment: @AksEyeless please provide an input sample or how it looks in console, when you run it...

Comment: @CLR123 Thanks for your response, I do input following "Aks Eyeless 2022"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how to enter the name and age on one line.

```
Please enter your name and age: Gilbert Le Blanc 66
Your age is: 66
Your name is: Gilbert Le Blanc
```

You perform a `Scanner` `nextLine` method, and then you parse (separate) the age from the name.  The [String](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) class has lots of useful methods for parsing a string.

Here's the modified code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Experiment {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        try {
            System.out.print("Please enter your name and age: ");

            String text = input.nextLine();
            int endIndex = text.lastIndexOf(' ');
            String name = text.substring(0, endIndex);
            int age = Integer.valueOf(text.substring(endIndex + 1));

            System.out.println("Your age is: " + age);
            System.out.println("Your name is: " + name);
        } finally {
            input.close();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried using input.next() instead of input.nextLine();

Comment: Not yet, I will try just now, thanks.

Comment: Sorry, it doesnt work, I get an error: Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to int

Comment: @AksEyeless it depends what is your input... I read the question now, it failed, because with `next()` you need to read name and family name separately, that's why it's failing - converting family name to `int`...

Comment: Hi @Betlista Thanks for your answer, my goal is to input 'myname' together with age '20'

Answer (score 0):

separate name and age declaration, to more understandably. and you can write try with resourses

```
    try (Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        
        System.out.println("Please enter your name: ");
        String name = input.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Please enter your age: ");
        int age = input.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Your age is: " + age);
        System.out.println("Your name is: " + name);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

*First things first: welcome to StackOverflow :D*

## Your Problem

It seems like you're providing your input the wrong way. I tested it locally and it works just fine, but you have to be careful about the way you input data.
`nextLine()` is going to read from the StandardOutput until it reaches a `\n` aka new-line character. On the other hand `nextInt()` is going to read the next Integer until it reaches a space. So what happens is: you input your data all in one line (f.e. `stackoverflow 2022`) sepparated by a space and hit enter. This will get saved in your variable `name`. Then, the console waits for your integer input. If you input some number, it will successfully print out the name (`stackoverflow 2022`) and age.

## Solution

*If you just want your code to work:*

Hit enter after you input the name and then type the number: your code works!

*If you 100% must provide the input in a single line:*

1. Use `next()` instead of `nextLine()`. That will read until a space, but be careful though: if the names you input contain spaces, the rest will be interpreted as integer and you will probably run into `InputMismatchException`-s

## General Recommendations:

You could try making your programm more interactive by asking the user to type their name and age specifically.

Another important change would be some better Exception-Handling, for example when the user is prompted to type an integer, but he/she provides a String.

Feel free to discuss your changes/ problems/ ideas/ thoughts in the comments :D

Comment: Hey Kristi, thanks a lot you have an amazing mind! Now I understand, and I did tested after I input 'myname 2022' it just did nothing and then I entered random number and it said that my name is: myname and age is 2022. But what I still don't understand is why does it prioritazes to search for the next Integer when I tell the program by indexing code block of STRING as first and > then I put int on the next line, so maybe he can look afterwards for int, Idk :D sorry I would like to express it precisely for your to understand what I meant but anyways problem is somehow solved.

Comment: Hey Aks, I don't completely understand your question, but here goes: nextLine reads whatever the **line** contains and saves it in a string. If you want it to search in the same line for a string and an int, then try using next() just like Syed's answer suggested.
What do you precisely mean by prioritizing? :D